# Transpose array in countifs formula - error

Tags: arrays, vba, sum

[image: Data Structure]

The picture gives a schematic representation of the data. Columns up to 17th in the actual spreadsheet is the raw data entries.

First I sort Brand according to SUMIF and add the Brand Month Sorted into an array - ArrayCurrentMonth. 
Then I add individual categories into Specialty Array.

Now what I want is to countifs number of entries with COUNTIFS formula for columns that are schematically pictured 9-12  using  ArrayCurrentMonth and Specialty as Range arguments in SUM(COUNTIFS(.. function

Thus 10-12 - ArrayCurrentMonth transposed ;
Column 9 - Specialty Values

Rammaged through earlier Q&A's and found useful variants, that seems to work for others, but for me on **Transpose** I stubbornly get **Sub or Function Not defined** no matter how i use it - with Range or with Array.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(X;Y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C:C"), RTrim(Month(Mesyaz1)), Range("H:H"), "Headephones", Transpose(Range("F:F"), ArrayCurrentMonth(c)), Range("L:L"), Specialty(g)))
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Range(X;Y) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("C:C"), "Month1", Range("H:H"), "Product1", Transpose(ArrayCurrentMonth), Range("L:L"), Specialty(g)))
```

or any other way I could think of just to check how it would work.

I would try looping For g=1 etc but I guess I need some `Transpose`  anyhow

Would be grateful for some tips.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Range(X:Y)` instead of `.Range(X;Y)` ?

Comment: Well It is just an example, I put it this way just not to overload with info. It is ActiveSheet.Range("AU2:AZ2") in fact.

Comment: I am intended to use empty column or row here depending on how i would arrange data

Comment: So here I need loop through two arrays starting with one cell